# formatting dynamic folder path within JSON

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

looking for basic code format help.

I want to replace this code:

```
{
"name": "BlobConnect",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "BlobConnect",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "typeProperties": {
        "fileName": "",
        "folderPath": "timtesting"
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"}
```

With something that dynamically assigns folder paths with whatever the current date is.  Another user suggested using:

```
"folderPath": {
      "value": "@concat('test1/',
                formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'-', 
                formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM'),'-',
                formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd'))",
       "type": "Expression"}
```

but every time I replace the folder path section with this I continue to get formatting errors.  I'm not sure what exactly is wrong, several formatting sites confirm it's not correct but I am not sure how to fix.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
"name": "BlobConnect",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "BlobConnect",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "typeProperties": {
        "fileName": "",
        "folderPath": {
            "value": "@concat('timtesting/', formatdatetime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'-',formatdatetime(utcnow(),'MM'),'-',formatdatetime(utcnow(),'dd'))",
            "type": "Expression"
        }
    }
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
```

}